# Wrap text to new line in DataGridview cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Good afternoon!

The DataGridView column has the following text:

| Title (Dep) |
| --- |
| programmer (IT infrastcomcture) |
| programmer (IT infrastcomcture) |
| System Administrator(IT infrastcomcture) |
| programmer (IT infrastcomcture) |
| engineer(IT infrastcomcture) |
| System Administrator(IT infrastcomcture) |

The height of the rows in the DataGridView is set to:

```vb
DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 44
```

Tell me, how can I move the test, which is contained in brackets, to a new line in the cell?

All cells in the Datagridview column should look like this:

```
programmer 
IT infrastcomcture
```

You can of course do this:

```vb
DataGridView1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
```

But this code won't work. I want that, regardless of the width of the column, the text that is indicated in brackets will be transferred to a new line in the cell

Comment: The DataGridView's RowTemplate supports wrapping and handles standard `Environment.NewLine` to separates lines of text.

Comment: the point is that the datagridview is already populated. and I can't write
`DataGridView1.Rows.Add("programmer" & Environment.NewLine & "IT infrastcomcture")` How to make a line wrap in a cell already in a filled datagridview?

Comment: You can handle the `CellFormatting` event for that. E.g., after filtering (to verify it's the correct Cell and its `Value` is not `null` or `DbNull.Value` or already contains `Environment.NewLine`, you can have: `dim sb = new StringBuilder([Cell Text]).Replace("(IT", $"{Environment.NewLine}(IT") e.Value = sb.ToString()` -- BTW, what is `infrastcomcture` :)